# ListView Card layout Scrollbar and spacing issues

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollbar

I have attached a screenshot of my app with some junk data. The white that takes up the entire ListView is supposed to only be for each item, creating a card layout. I am new to Android, and cannot figure out where my code makes the incorrect reference.

The layout for the individual card is here: http://pastebin.com/mxjiDTLF

The layout for the activity is here: http://pastebin.com/kstW9PqV

The EventAdapter.java class that displays the Event objects in the listview is here: http://pastebin.com/vXkBnPq0

Also, in the below screenshot, you can see that the scrollbar does not appear right next to the left edge of the screen, but just inside the "white" of the massive card. What do I need to do so that it does not appear there?

[image]

Comment: please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most layout parameters are ignored for ListViewItems. You should wrap the contents in the list view item inside another layout that has the correct margins, something like here (not tested): http://pastebin.com/bW7s27in

The fact that your scrollbar is not at the edge of the screen is caused by the margins of the ListView in your activity_events.xml file. You should set those to 0.

Comment: In addition to this, it turns out that to have the scrollbar on the outside of the"invisible" space surrounding the card where the light grey is, I had to use an inset xml file, and put my previous card xml file as an inset. That gave me the ability to control how far away from the edge the scrollbar is.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the card background to each item.